# Executing AutoIt script from command prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt, autoit, shellexecute

Is there any way to execute my AutoIt script (.au3 file) from command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could compile your AutoIt script and run the .exe from the command line.

Or, you can run the script like this:

`AutoIt3.exe myscript.au3`

Comment: I have script named "helloworld.au3" on D:\Ripon. I went to that location and ran the command:

AutoIt3.exe helloworld.au3

But an error was occurred as below:

D:\Ripon>AutoIt3.exe helloworld.au3
'AutoIt3.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
D:\Ripon>

Is there any more installation/configuration of AutoIt?

Comment: You need to specify the full path to `AutoIt3.exe`. For example, `C:\Apps\AutoIt\AutoIt3.exe helloworld.au3`.

Answer (score 3):

The default installation of autoit makes .au3 files runnable from the command line by just using

c:>\script.au3